# Simple Laplacian operator on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: laplacian

Let

\begin{cases}
 x=\sin \theta \cos \varphi     \\
 y= \sin \theta \sin \varphi \\
 z= \cos \theta
  \end{cases}

Then we obtain

$$g_{\mathbb{S}^2} = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1& 0  \\
  0 & \sin^2 \theta 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Hence, $$\det (g_{\mathbb{S}^2})= \sin^2 \theta$$

Furthermore,

$$\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det (g_{\mathbb{S}^2})}} \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i} (\sqrt{\det (g_{\mathbb{S}^2})} g_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}) = \frac{1}{ \sin \theta} (\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\sin \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi} (\sin \theta  \frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi})) $$

$$=  \frac{1}{ \sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\sin \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta})+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \varphi^2}. $$

As final answer, I'm supposed to obtain $\frac{1}{ \sin \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\sin \theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta})+ \frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta}  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \varphi^2}$, but I just don't know where is my mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: Your definition for the Laplace Beltrami operator is incorrect. You should have a squareroot of a determinant inside the derivatives and an inverse metric. This will invert the components in the metric and give you the correct answer. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace–Beltrami_operator

Comment: The determinant, it is fine... It was just a mistake, but what do you mean by inverse metric... Is it simply $g_{\mathbb{S}^2}^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, the metric with indices "up". Just invert the matrix